# Photoshop animation dropping frames at 12fps or as image sequence

Tags: after-effects, animation, framerate, animation-rendering, compositing

I have been kind of tearing my hair out trying to figure this out. I have a frame animation with 30 frames. I tried exporting it as a video set to 12fps. For some reason, what should be 2.5 seconds (30 frames at 12fps) is dropping down to 2 seconds on export. I thought it was some weird video codec glitch, but I discovered that the same thing happens when I export as an image sequence: Even though I have checked several times that "All Frames" was selected (other options are disabled anyway), I find only 24 pngs in my sequence where there should be 30.

Any help with this? It's a frame-by-frame rotoscoped animation so switching from frame animation to a timeline animation doesn't quite work. I know I can export frames manually by saving each frame one at a time, but it would be lovely to not have to do that (or to find a script that can do this for me to save time). The goal is to import the sequence to After Effects for additional animation/compositing.

I'll gladly share screenshots later tonight when I'm at my animation computer again.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do the frame rate change in Photoshop.  Do it later on in AE.  Export all 30 frames from Photoshop, then import them into AE.  Make a new comp in AE, setting the new frame rate as 12fps in the comp settings.

Right click on your image sequence and choose "interpret footage as 12fps".

Comment: Do you mean that I should be exporting each frame manually? Because I was hoping for a workaround that uses what should be built-in functionality to export as an image sequence :( The image sequence export is dropping frames, too.

Comment: I think what he was saying is that you should export the animation as an image sequence, which gives you 30 single frames. Then, in AE you set these 30 frames to be running at 12fps.